# How to implement AirBnB like localization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, localization

I'm trying to localize my Rails apps for several countries.
I want to implement it like AirBnB. Locale based subdomains and www subdomain.

```
www.myapp.com
jp.myapp.com
kr.myapp.com
```

At first, users enter locale subdomain site or www subdomain site. If the user enter localized page or set their language in the www subdomain page, set cookie param [:locale].

AirBnB use Ruby on Rails for development, but how they manipulate many subdomains? They have multiple apps for each locale or just One app? Could I implement this on Heroku?

I checked this RailsCasts Episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised?view=asciicast , but it uses passenger, so I doubt whether I can use this solution for Heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly acheivable on Heroku - use a wildcard domain so your application is available on *.myapp.com and then set the language based on the subdomain. The ruby on rails guides have a section on it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-domain-name). In summary, you would need to do something like (in your application_controller.rb);

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_subdomain || I18n.default_locale
end

# Get locale code from request subdomain (like http://it.lvh.me:3000)
# lvh.me is a free service which maps ANY subdomain to 127.0.0.1 so
# en.lvh.me, it.lvh.me etc would all redirect to 127.0.0.1
def extract_locale_from_subdomain
  parsed_locale = request.subdomains.first
  I18n.available_locales.include?(parsed_locale.to_sym) ? parsed_locale : nil
end
```